# SQLite how to sum values from another table from a delimited column text?

Tags: sqlite

Sorry if my question is a duplicate, I'll delete if it is but I couldn't find what I want to do anywhere else. Perhaps I don't know how to ask it.

I have 3 tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Order;
CREATE TABLE Order(
  ORD_ID integer primary key
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Product;
CREATE TABLE Product(
  PRO_ID integer primary key
, PRO_Price double
, PRO_Kind integer
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OrderItems;
CREATE TABLE OrderItems(
  ORI_ID integer primary key
, ORD_ID integer
, PRO_ID integer
, ORI_AddedIngredients varchar
, FOREIGN KEY (PRO_ID) REFERENCES Product(PRO_ID)
, FOREIGN KEY (ORD_ID) REFERENCES Order(ORD_ID)
);
```

The content of them is this:

```
Table Product
=========================================
PRO_ID | PRO_Price | PRO_Kind 
1        5           1
2        11          1
3        2           2
4        2           2
5        2           2
=========================================

Table OrderItems WHERE ORD_ID = 1
=========================================
ORI_ID | ORD_ID | PRO_ID | ORI_AddedIngredients 
1        1        1        '3, 4'
2        1        1        null
3        1        2        null
4        1        1        null
5        1        1        null
6        1        1        '3, 4, 5'
=========================================
```

I wanna make a query that returns the sum value from the table considering the addedingredients to the product as well, but products that have addedingredients are different from products that don't have added ingredients

The result would be something like this:

```
QUERY RESULT
========================================
ORD_ID | PRO_ID | Total
1        1        9
1        1        5
1        1        11
1        2        11
```

But I don't know how to read the IDs from the field that has them like an array, I can make the query without it just fine, but when I have to include them I don't know how to do.

If you guys have a better way of organizing the contents of the table, please lemme know.

Answer (score 1):

You must join `OrderItems` to 2 copies of `Product` and aggregate:

```
SELECT oi.ORI_ID, oi.ORD_ID, oi.PRO_ID,
       MAX(p1.PRO_Price) + COALESCE(SUM(p2.PRO_Price), 0) Total
FROM OrderItems oi 
INNER JOIN Product p1 ON p1.PRO_ID = oi.PRO_ID
LEFT JOIN Product p2 ON ',' || REPLACE(oi.ORI_AddedIngredients, ' ', '') || ',' LIKE  '%,' || p2.PRO_ID || ',%'
GROUP BY oi.ORI_ID, oi.ORD_ID, oi.PRO_ID
```

If there are no spaces in the column `ORI_AddedIngredients` then instead of `REPLACE(oi.ORI_AddedIngredients, ' ', '')` use `ORI_AddedIngredients`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=56b436b66ee110b042cd524983d2fe24).
Results:

```
> ORI_ID | ORD_ID | PRO_ID | Total
> -----: | -----: | -----: | ----:
>      1 |      1 |      1 |     9
>      2 |      1 |      1 |     5
>      3 |      1 |      2 |    11
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic on the LEFT JOIN line, it would translate to something like:
`LEFT JOIN Product p2 ON ',' || null || ',' LIKE '%,' || 1 || ',%'`
That is comparing what to what?

Comment: In the case where `ORI_AddedIngredients` is `null` there will be no match for this LEFT join, so `COALESCE(SUM(p2.PRO_Price), 0)` will be `0`.

Comment: taking the example, where its products 3 and 4 as ingredients of the order 1, the LEFT JOIN line would be: `LEFT JOIN Product p2 ON ',3,4,' LIKE '%,' || 1 || ',%'`? How that will search the table Product comparing if the product 3 exists? Sorry I don't get the logic on this line

Comment: It is not: `...LIKE '%,' || 1 || ',%'`, it is `LIKE  '%,' || p2.PRO_ID || ',%'` and `p2` is a 2nd copy of `Product` and all of its rows are compared against `',' || REPLACE(oi.ORI_AddedIngredients, ' ', '') || ','`

Comment: So it would compare like an 'IN' statement? like comparing if the string is inside an array, like `'3,4 IN [1,2,3,4]`? But in this case would be converting to a literal comparison with the LIKE command, that's the how?

Comment: IN operates on a list of values, but `ORI_AddedIngredients` is a string that contains a comma separated list of values, this is why you can't use IN but you can use LIKE which operates on strings. But yes, this is the general idea.

Comment: @Mobiusone is there a reason that you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: Tested here but it didn't work on a bigger table. The total value isn't resulting 9 on an item with 2 ingredients and the other products with same ID but without added ingredients on the same order are being listed separatedly, they should be collapsed, I'll edit the main post with more stuff to illustrate it

Comment: @Mobiusone this code answers the question as you posted it. If you have a different requirement you can post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the query provided by @forpas I was able to build the query that produces the result I wanted for the question, Thanks @forpas:

```
SELECT
  oi.ORD_ID
, oi.PRO_ID
, MAX(p1.PRO_ID) + COALESCE(SUM(p2.PRO_Price),0) Total
FROM OrderItems oi
JOIN Product p1 ON p1.PRO_ID = oi.PRO_ID
LEFT JOIN Product p2 ON ',' || REPLACE(oi.ORI_AddedIngredients, ' ', '') || ',' LIKE '%,' || p2.PRO_ID || ',%'
GROUP BY oi.PRO_ID, oi.ORD_ID, oi.ORI_AddedIngredients
```

The key points on this query:

- REPLACE is needed so the LIKE comparison works correctly, if it has any blank spots, it'll only sum one of the ingredients instead of all of them
- Collapsing the ingredients that have the same value for ORI_AddedIngredients is just as simple as adding the field on the GROUP BY clause, so same product IDs with different ingredients takes different row spots
- Without using REPLACE, I managed to find out that the code was recording blank spaces in the database instead of just the delimited text with the IDs, but I kept it in the query because sometime in the future if I forget and end up adding blank spaces it'll still work.

Again, thanks @forpas for providing the query and the explainig on how you did it. The explaining was more valuable than just posting the answer, thanks.

EDIT: After a couple of days working on the query to try to fetch the final result on every possible combination of situations, I gave up trying to sum the ingredients to the product base value multiplied by the amount of products of that order, probably because I don't know how to do it properly but I split the value into 2 columns and whenever I want the total, I just sum them.
Here's the final result, yes it is adapted to my particular use case.

```
SELECT
  ip.IPE_ID
, ip.PED_ID
, ip.PRO_ID
, p1.PRO_Nome
, ip.IPE_Adicionados
, ip.IPE_Removidos
, (SELECT COUNT(ip2.PRO_ID)
   FROM ItensPedido ip2
   WHERE ip2.PRO_ID = ip.PRO_ID
     AND ip2.PED_ID = ip.PED_ID
     AND (ip2.IPE_Adicionados = ip.IPE_Adicionados
      OR ip2.IPE_Removidos = ip.IPE_Removidos
      OR ip.IPE_Adicionados is null AND ip.IPE_Removidos is null
         )
   GROUP BY IPE_Adicionados
  ) as IPE_Qtd
, COALESCE(SUM(p2.PRO_Preco),0) as IPE_PIngredientes
, (SELECT COUNT(ip2.PRO_ID) * ip2.IPE_Valor
     FROM ItensPedido ip2        
    WHERE ip2.PRO_ID = ip.PRO_ID
     AND ip2.PED_ID = ip.PED_ID
     AND (ip2.IPE_Adicionados = ip.IPE_Adicionados
      OR ip2.IPE_Removidos = ip.IPE_Removidos
      OR ip.IPE_Adicionados is null AND ip.IPE_Removidos is null
         )
   GROUP BY IPE_Adicionados
  ) as IPE_PParcial
FROM ItensPedido ip
JOIN Produto p1 ON p1.PRO_ID = ip.PRO_ID
LEFT JOIN Produto p2 
       ON "," || REPLACE(ip.IPE_Adicionados, " ", "") || "," LIKE "%," || p2.PRO_ID || ",%" 
WHERE ip.PED_ID = :PED_ID
GROUP BY p1.PRO_Nome, ip.PED_ID, ip.IPE_Adicionados, ip.IPE_Removidos
```

And this is one example result on my test database:

```
IPE_ID  PED_ID  PRO_ID  PRO_Nome            IPE_Adicionados IPE_Removidos   IPE_Qtd IPE_PIngredientes   IPE_PParcial
7       1       1       Hamburguer          null            null            2       0                   10
1       1       1       Hamburguer          28, 29          null            2       8                   10
9       1       1       Hamburguer          28, 29, 30      null            1       6                   5
2       1       37      Refrigerante Lata   null            null            2       0                   8
3       1       7       X-Bacon             null            46, 47          1       0                   11
```

Comment: This query does not return your expected results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1a98bcd21edfed6e96651f328f8ed44d

Comment: I only detected 1 issue so far that is the collapsed record totals aren't being sum, so its like product with ID 1 even having 3 occurrencies of it in the table, it is only showing the price of 1, instead of the sum of all 3. Other than that its working... This site that you use to test queries I don't know about it, never used and the link is showing 404 error to me. I use SQLite express to manipulate my queries and the results provided by it are the same that I have in my app. And on it the query above works.

Comment: The previous link is valid and this is another one: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wuWX5drNfnExVWF4RBYgMS/0

Comment: @forpas this .com link worked for me but for some reason the .uk isn't working, probably has something to do with my ISP. Thanks for providing help forpas, I really apreciate it.